# How best to export functions in dynamic modules

Tags: help, modules

#### Background

I am running Emacs version

```el
GNU Emacs 26.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2017-05-28
```

I am writing a toy dynamic module to interface with GNU/Linux utilities following [this guide](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/11/05/). My module compiles, loads and runs successfully, but the information reported by the help system leaves something to be desired. Is there a way to achieve the same level of integration as with built-in functions?

#### Module definition

My module `foo.c` (which compiles to `foo.so`) includes the following:

```c
#define FOO_DOC "Frobnicate BAR.\n\n(fn BAR)"

static emacs_value Ffoo (/* ... args ... */) { /* ... body ... */ }

int
emacs_module_init (struct emacs_runtime *ert)
{
  emacs_value Qfset, Qprovide, Qfoo, Sfoo;
  emacs_env *env = ert->get_environment (ert);

  Qfset    = env->intern (env, "fset");
  Qprovide = env->intern (env, "provide");
  Qfoo     = env->intern (env, "foo");
  Sfoo     = env->make_function (env, 1, 1, Ffoo, FOO_DOC, NULL);

  env->funcall (env, Qfset,    2, (emacs_value[]) {Qfoo, Sfoo});
  env->funcall (env, Qprovide, 1, &Qfoo);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Desired behaviour

Here is an example of what `describe-function` reports for `mapc`:

```el
mapc is a built-in function in ‘src/fns.c’.

(mapc FUNCTION SEQUENCE)

Apply FUNCTION to each element of SEQUENCE for side effects only.
Unlike ‘mapcar’, don’t accumulate the results.  Return SEQUENCE.
SEQUENCE may be a list, a vector, a bool-vector, or a string.
```

where the quoted filename `src/fns.c` forms a link to the function's definition.

#### Actual behaviour

When the module function `foo` is defined using `fset`, as per the source listing above and the linked blog post, `describe-function` reports the following:

```el
foo is .

(foo BAR)

Frobnicate BAR.
```

Furthermore, inspecting `load-history` reveals the following:

```el
("/path/to/baz.el"
 (require . foo)
 (provide . foo)
 ;; ... other baz.el definitions ...
 (provide . baz))
```

where `baz.el` calls `(require 'foo)` and which itself gets loaded as part of my startup.

---

If I replace `fset` with `defalias` in the module, I instead get:

```el
foo is in ‘baz.el’.

(foo BAR)

Frobnicate BAR.
```

and `load-history` includes an additional `defun`:

```el
("/path/to/baz.el"
 (require . foo)
 (defun   . foo)
 (provide . foo)
 ;; ... other baz.el definitions ...
 (provide . baz))
```

#### Questions

1. How can I tell Emacs that the function `foo` is a function and defined in the dynamic module `foo.c`, not the elisp file which loaded it, `baz.el`?
2. Does the help system support links to module sources?
3. Is there a better way to export module functions than the described `defalias` approach?
4. Is there a better way to load a module than `(require 'module-feature)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell Emacs that the function `foo` is a function and defined in the dynamic module `foo.c`, not the elisp file which loaded it, `baz.el`?

[Emacs 27 now knows this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=0443411f5ce2594a6ec092cd96b92d0b920372f5). Well, technically it knows that `foo` is a function defined in `foo.so`, but you can then translate this to `foo.c` pretty easily, e.g.:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string (rx (eval module-file-suffix) eos)
                          ".c" (symbol-file 'foo))
  ;; ⇒ "/path/to/foo.c"
```

> Does the help system support links to module sources?

To an extent. It [now](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=f3d0db7f0f9639ec0198d4f4f2c3eb9c7b495778) reports:

```
foo is a module function in `foo.so'.

(foo BAR)

Frobnicate BAR.
```

where `foo.so` is linked to the `.so` file, not the location where `foo` is defined in `foo.c`, as is usually the case for built-in subroutines. Better support may be added in the future.

> Is there a better way to export module functions than the described `defalias` approach?

[No](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=75c663f834528c5431973bf8dc6386c327f9fe0f).

> Is there a better way to load a module than `(require 'module-feature)`?

[No](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/test/src/emacs-module-tests.el?id=0443411f5ce2594a6ec092cd96b92d0b920372f5#n33).